# autohotkeysc.bin sourcecode?

Tags: autohotkey

i know that autohotkey is opensource software. but i need 'autohotkeysc.bin' 's source code
how could i get it ? or does anyone have exe2ahk.exe (autohotkey decompiler) source code ?

```
this is junk code
// Copy our sc.bin file to the destination
if ( (fbin = fopen(m_szAutoItSC, "rb")) == NULL)
{
    SetCursor(LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW)); // Reset cursor
    Util_ShowErrorIDS(IDS_E_READSCBIN);
    return false;
}

// Open the dest file (overwrite if required)
if ( (fdest = fopen(szDest, "w+b")) == NULL )
{
    SetCursor(LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW)); // Reset cursor
    fclose(fbin);
    Util_ShowErrorIDS(IDS_E_WRITEDEST);
    return false;
}

// Copy the bin file to the destination then close the bin file
while ( fread(&ch, 1, 1, fbin) != 0)
    fwrite(&ch, 1, 1, fdest);

fclose(fbin);                               // Close sc.bin
fclose(fdest);                              // Close destination
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the source code for AutoHotkey_L is on [GitHub](https://github.com/Lexikos/AutoHotkey_L).

AutoHotkeySC.bin is generated after AutoHotkey.exe is compiled.  The process is done by [this script](https://github.com/Lexikos/AutoHotkey_L/blob/master/PostBuildSC.ahk).